# Generate a type from a module's own exported keys

Tags: typescript, typescript2.1

Given a module like this:

```
export const a: string;
export const b: string;
```

From outside you can generate a type `"a" | "b"` like this:

```
import * as stuff from "./stuff";
type StuffKeys = keyof typeof stuff; // "a" | "b"
```

But I want to generate and export this type from *within the module*. Something like:

```
export type MyKeys = keyof typeof this;
```

But that does not work.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not believe, that what you are planning to do was possible, as the line `export type MyKeys...` would have neede to be included in the keys type itself.

However, surprisingly it is working to just import the module into itself and exporting the keys from there.

**main.ts**

```
export const a : string = 'a';
export const b : string = 'b';

import * as main from './main'
export type MyKeys = keyof typeof main;
```

**test.ts**

```
import {MyKeys} from './main';

const a : MyKeys = 'a';
const b : MyKeys = 'c'; // TS2322: Type '"c"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'.
```

Comment: Note that if you want to define the type inside the same module assuming it is called `foo.ts` you could do the following:

type Exports = keyof typeof import('./foo')